# Should I answer a question concerning an outdated version of technology?

Tags: discussion, questions, outdated-information

I came across a question that probably addresses an outdated version of technology (be it software tool or framework). In the recent version, the answer to the question is so obvious to find that I can't believe anyone would ask the question now.

An example of such a question would be [Visual Studio Code built-in hard wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40070003/7769052). Someone is looking for a possibility to use hard wrapping instead of soft wrapping in Visual Studio Code (software development tool). They want to set it for Markdown only as well. Hard wrapping has full support in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) now. One can use <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd> shortcut or use settings. One can add overrides for markdown language specifically. So I think the solution is too obvious and the question must have been asked during the earlier developmental stage of Visual Studio Code.

What should I do? Should I answer the question or flag it for moderator intervention or flag it for closing?

Comment: Answer the question if you know how. Outdated technologies do not magically disappear from the face of the earth. People continue using them, voluntarily or not.

Comment: In this particular case, the question looks at a glance like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122175/1709587 (which is more highly-viewed and has answers), so perhaps the right approach is actually to flag to close as a dupe of that and to add your answer *there* if somebody hasn't done so already.

Comment: Deleted my answer since there is already dupe both for main and meta :p

Comment: Also, as an aside, if you think that something having a shortcut and an entry in a settings menu means that it is now *"so obvious to find"* that nobody would ever ask about it, then you are terribly, terrible naive about how capable users are of finding functionality in a GUI, *especially* in one as big and complicated as an IDE. My [third-highest-upvoted answer ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931752/1709587) is just some screenshots pointing out where to find a function in Xcode, in a dropdown menu that's literally always one click away via a button next to the code-writing pane.